# how to add next/prev buttons to uikit tabs

Tags: jquery, uikit

hi friends i use uikit framework but i have a little problem with it
for default the switcher ( tab ) componnet in uikit don't have this feature it has a attrib value named active that we can set the default tab when page load but i cant use it to go to next/prev tab with navigation buttons
here is the code that i use

```
<ul id="ad-adtab" class="ad-tab uk-tab uk-tab-grid" data-uk-tab="{connect:'#ad-additem', animation: 'fade', active:0}">
<li class="ad-step1 uk-width-1-4"><a href="">item</a></li>
<li class="ad-step2 uk-width-1-4"><a href="">item2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="ad-additem" class="ad-switcher uk-switcher uk-margin">
<li>content 1</li>
<li>content 2</li>
</ul>
<a class="ad-next">next</a>
```

and here the jquery that i use to go to next tab

```
$('.ad-next').on('click', function(){
        $('.ad-tab').attr( "data-uk-tab", "connect:'#ad-additem', animation: 'fade', active:1" );
    });
```

but it wont work please help me to make a navigation link for tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within the content you can use this code:

```
<li> ... <a href="" data-uk-switcher-item="next">...</a></li>
<li> ... <a href="" data-uk-switcher-item="previous">...</a></li>
```

or to switch to a specific tab:

```
<li> ... <a href="" data-uk-switcher-item="0">...</a></li>
<li> ... <a href="" data-uk-switcher-item="1">...</a></li>
```